# Solr collection API backup exception Timeout exception | "Could not backup all shards" | Directory containing snapshot doesnot exist

Tags: collections, solr, backup, timeoutexception

I was trying to backup around 20 million datas in solr through solr collection api backup.
But getting timeout exception soon after executing the backup query in pod. adding stacktrace below:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{

    "status":500,
    "QTime":120693},
  "failure":{

    "perfrandom-solr-backup-solr-0.perfrandom-solr-backup-solr:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:Timeout occurred while waiting response from server at: http://perfrandom-solr-backup-solr-0.perfrandom-solr-backup-solr:8983/solr"},
  "Operation backup caused exception:":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not backup all shards",
  "exception":{

    "msg":"Could not backup all shards",
    "rspCode":500},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Could not backup all shards",

:Failed to backup core=foo_signals_shard1_replica_n2 because org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Directory to contain snapshots doesn't exist: file:///vol1/cloud84/backups/sigs


    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not backup all shards\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse.getException(SolrResponse.java:64)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:282)\n\tat
```

I created a random instance where on of the pod is solr pod , and that contains 20 million records.
then executed backup query from the nginx pod, and it returned this exception.